# HTTP url connection Android

Tags: android, http, connection

I am having trouble getting my app to open a connection to the URL that is a JSON file online. I followed guidelines how out to get the inBackground thread to fetch the URL, though when I call .connect() on that URL it seems to return out of the inBackground function because I tested just having a String that would be modified and displayed as a Toast, and modifying the String right after httpConn.connect() caused no change at all. I made sure my permissions were right in the manifest, but perhaps there is something small I am overlooking.

```
protected String doInBackground(URL... urls){

        InputStream in = null;
        String result = "test";
        int responseCode = -1;
        try {
            URL url = urls[0];
            URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
            if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
                throw new IOException("URL is not an Http URL");
            }
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.setDoInput(true);

            result = "get here";
            httpConn.connect();
            result = "don't get here";

            responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
            httpConn.disconnect();
            result = readIt(in, 10);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Any ideas of what is causing there not to be any connection or how to test if I am simply overlooking or not completely understanding this? I can additional code if needed. Thank you

Comment: Please, post `AsyncTask` class code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am getting ,You want to connect to a web url which returns json response .Am I right ? If yes then you need to visit [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) link for complete solution .

Comment: Thank you! Just what I am looking for, I will try this out later today.

Comment: I got it to work, my problem was that I wasn't executing my AsyncTask the right way.

Comment: Submit another question ,with the AsyncTask code ,and mention that link here .I will answer you .